# Search box on a observable collection tree view in wpf

Tags: wpf, treeview, observablecollection

I am having a text box and a tree view of observable collections. I need to filter the observable collection in the tree view according to the text value of the text box.
All the list starts with the matching text should be displayed

Comment: Do you mean like the search box present in Solution Explorer of Visual Studio (say 2012) version?

Comment: yes exactly the same.I had done it for Parent records. I cant able to achieve it for the children.

Comment: Fine, then you need to re-check your search logic; To traverse to each and every node from the root observable collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function in MVVM invoked when key down on the text Box

```
public void SearchChild()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchFilter))
            {
                var ChildList = new ObservableCollection<TestArtifact>();
                foreach (var n in FolderItems)
                {
                    if (n.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchFilter.Trim().ToLower()))
                    {
                        ChildList.Add(n);
                        continue;
                    }
                    var a = (n.Children).Where((x) => x.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchFilter.Trim().ToLower())).ToList();
                    if (a.Count > 0)
                    {
                        n.Children = null;
                        n.Children = a;
                        ChildList.Add(n);
                    }
                }
                SearchFolderItems = new ObservableCollection<TestArtifact>(ChildList);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SearchFolderItems);
                return;
            }
            SearchFolderItems = FolderItems;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SearchFolderItems);

        }
```

The Xaml code..

```
<TextBox x:Name="SearchScript" Text="{Binding SearchFilter,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Text}" 
                    Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" cal:Message.Attach="[Event KeyUp] = [Action SearchChild]" />

<TreeView x:Name="FolderView" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchFolderItems, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="{Binding ElementName=Editor,Path=Margin}">
```

Answer (score 1):

What is a "a tree view of observable collections"? Is it really a tree view of an observable collection?

Filtering it can become quite tricky to a user. What should happen when a parent node is filtered out? Should its' children be filtered out as well, even thought they satisfy?

Anyway, bind a view model property to the text box. In the setter do your filtering logic. Bind the tree view to the separate list which will contain only satisfying records. Another option is using a CollectionView.

Comment: yes its a tree view of observable collection. I have to filter only the parent node not including the children nodes